# How to add Date Picker in Dynamic Add/Remove Custom Fields (Repeater Fields)

Tags: datepicker

I have created **Dynamic Add/Remove Custom Fields (Repeater Fields)** in my custom Post types. It is working perfectly. I want to add a new **JQuery Date Picker** field. I tried hard to create code and also searched the web but found no luck.

Plz Help me.

Following is my code.

```
function project_rewards_select_options() {
    $options = array (
        'Option 1' => 'Option 1',
        'Option 2' => 'Option 2',
        'Option 3' => 'Option 3',
    );

    return $options;
}

function project_reward_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'project_reward_nonce', 'project_reward_nonce' );
    $reward_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_project_rewards', true );
    $options = project_rewards_select_options();

?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
            var row = $( '.empty-row.screen-reader-text' ).clone(true);
            row.removeClass( 'empty-row screen-reader-text' );
            row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
            return false;
        });

        $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="15%">Reward Amount</th>
            <th width="25%">Reward Title</th>
            <th width="10%">Shipping</th>       
            <th width="45%">Reward Description</th>
            <th width="5%"></th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

<?php

    ( $reward_value );

    foreach ( $reward_value as $field ) {

?>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward[]" value="<?php if ( isset ( $field['reward'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $field['reward'] ); ?>" pattern="[1-9]\d*" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward_title[]" value="<?php if ( isset ( $field['reward_title'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $field['reward_title'] ); ?>" /></td>

        <td>
            <select class="widefat" name="reward_shipping[]">
            <?php foreach ( $options as $label => $value ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"<?php selected( $field['reward_shipping'], $value ); ?>><?php echo $label; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td><textarea class="widefat" name="reward_description[]"><?php if ( isset ( $field['reward_description'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $field['reward_description'] ); ?></textarea></td>

        <td><input type="image" class="remove-row" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/remove-icon.png" alt="Submit"  width="35" height="35"></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>

    <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
    <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward[]" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward_title[]" /></td>

        <td>
            <select class="widefat" name="reward_shipping[]">
            <?php foreach ( $options as $label => $value ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>   

        <td><textarea class="widefat" name="reward_description[]" ></textarea></td>

        <td><input type="image" class="remove-row" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/remove-icon.png" alt="Submit"  width="35" height="35"></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>

    <p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add Reward</a></p>

<?php   

}

function save_project_reward( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['project_reward_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['project_reward_nonce'], 'project_reward_nonce' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    }
    else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    $reward_data = array();
    $options = project_rewards_select_options();

    $rewards = $_POST['reward'];
    $reward_titles = $_POST['reward_title'];
    $reward_shippings = $_POST['reward_shipping'];
    $reward_descriptions = $_POST['reward_description'];

    $count = count( $rewards );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {

        if ( $rewards[$i] != '' ) :
            $reward_data[$i]['reward'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $rewards[$i] ) );

        if ( in_array( $reward_shippings[$i], $options ) )
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_shipping'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $reward_shippings[$i] ) );
                else
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_shipping'] = '';
endif;

        if ( $reward_titles[$i] != '' ) :
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_title'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $reward_titles[$i] ) );
endif;

        if ( $reward_descriptions[$i] != '' ) :
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_description'] = stripslashes( $reward_descriptions[$i] );
endif;              

    }

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_project_rewards', $reward_data );

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_project_reward' );
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add your own JQuery Date Picker if ACF already has this field?

Comment: I don't want to use ACF

Comment: Oh Sorry my bad, I understood that you were using it

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has the jQuery datepicker already included. So you can enqueue the default WP script. However, as far as I know, WP doesnt include the necessary styling for the datepicker!
So try to enqueue the WP script, and for example, styles from external source:

```
function my_datepicker_enqueue() {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ); // enqueue datepicker from WP
            wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-style', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css', true);
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_datepicker_enqueue' );
```

Create a new HTML input field with atleast with a class and a name.
HTML of the input field: (you already have some input fields defined, so jump to the script)

```
<input type="text" name="_custom_datepicker[]" id="_custom_datepicker[]" class="my-custom-datepicker-field" value="<?php echo $your_saved_value; ?>" />
```

Than add a script to init the datepicker for our new element.
Script: (make sure that you target the right input element, we are looking at the defined class here, cause we want to use multiple instances.)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-custom-datepicker-field').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', //maybe you want something like this
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```

---

**Update:**
I had some problems reading your code at first, and you also have several errors in your code. First I could see the same strange behaviour. I have now setup a testplugin on a dev site, and there it is now working.

**1:** You set up your save function so that you cannot just enter a date and save.
You will have to either add a amount, title or description also, to be able to save.
I think this is intended by you?

**2:** In the save function you have the following code:

```
if ( $reward_descriptions[$i] != '' ) :
    $reward_data[$i]['reward_date'] = stripslashes( $reward_dates[$i] );
endif;
```

So only when the description field is not empty the date will get saved?!
Seems this was a typo because the other fields look good.
Change to:

```
if ( $reward_data[$i] != '' ) :
    $reward_data[$i]['reward_date'] = stripslashes( $reward_dates[$i] );
endif;
```

**3:** In your callback code you have these fields as datepicker fields:

```
<td><input type="text" name="_custom_datepicker[]" id="_custom_datepicker[]" class="my-custom-datepicker-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $field['reward_date'] ); ?>" /></td>
```

and

```
<td><input type="text" class="my-custom-datepicker-field" name="_custom_datepicker[]" /></td>
```

Both named `_custom_datepicker[]`.
But in your save function you try to save fields called `reward_date` instead.

Also the `id` should be unique. But you add the same `id` to all datefields.
You could just remove the `id` from these fields, its not needed anyway.

**4.** If you add fields dynamically like you want to, you need to change the datepicker JS function.
And instead of loading the JS code inline (and multiple times like you did), I recommend enqueuing one JS file.
So try to replace your JS code with something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // your default code
    $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
        var row = $( '.empty-row.screen-reader-text' ).clone(true);
        row.removeClass( 'empty-row screen-reader-text' );
        row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
        return false;
    });

    $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });

    //changed to be used on dynamic field which gets added and removed from DOM
    //if the element with the class .my-custom-datepicker-field gets focus, add datepicker
    $(document).on('focus', '.my-custom-datepicker-field', function(){
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', //maybe you want something like this
            showButtonPanel: true
        });
    });

});
```

After I fixed these things and enqueued the JS file with the code like WordPress wants it to, it is now working.

Answer (score -1):

@LWS-Mo,
  Thanks for helping. I have added the codes accordingly but the datepicker is working weirdly. The date selected in first field get reflected in subsiquent field. Not working properly.

Plz tell me where I am getting wrong. Following is the code.

```
function project_rewards_select_options() {
    $options = array (
        'Option 1' => 'Option 1',
        'Option 2' => 'Option 2',
        'Option 3' => 'Option 3',
    );

    return $options;
}

function crazicle_project_reward_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'project_reward_nonce', 'project_reward_nonce' );
    $reward_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_project_rewards', true );
    $options = project_rewards_select_options();

?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
            var row = $( '.empty-row.screen-reader-text' ).clone(true);
            row.removeClass( 'empty-row screen-reader-text' );
            row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
            return false;
        });

        $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>

    <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="15%">Reward Amount</th>
            <th width="25%">Reward Title</th>
            <th width="10%">Shipping</th>
            <th width="20%">date</th>                  
            <th width="25%">Reward Description</th>
            <th width="5%"></th>                    
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

<?php

    ( $reward_value );

    foreach ( $reward_value as $field ) {

?>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward[]" value="<?php if ( isset ( $field['reward'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $field['reward'] ); ?>" pattern="[1-9]\d*" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward_title[]" value="<?php if ( isset ( $field['reward_title'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $field['reward_title'] ); ?>" /></td>

        <td>
            <select class="widefat" name="reward_shipping[]">
            <?php foreach ( $options as $label => $value ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"<?php selected( $field['reward_shipping'], $value ); ?>><?php echo $label; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-custom-datepicker-field').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', //maybe you want something like this
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
        </script>

        <td><input type="text" name="_custom_datepicker[]" id="_custom_datepicker[]" class="my-custom-datepicker-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $field['reward_date'] ); ?>" /></td>

        <td><textarea class="widefat" name="reward_description[]"><?php if ( isset ( $field['reward_description'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $field['reward_description'] ); ?></textarea></td>

        <td><input type="image" class="remove-row" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/remove-icon.png" alt="Submit"  width="35" height="35"></td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>

    <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
    <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward[]" /></td>

        <td><input type="text" class="widefat" name="reward_title[]" /></td>

        <td>
            <select class="widefat" name="reward_shipping[]">
            <?php foreach ( $options as $label => $value ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-custom-datepicker-field').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', //maybe you want something like this
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
        </script>        

        <td><input type="text" class="my-custom-datepicker-field" name="_custom_datepicker[]" /></td>          

        <td><textarea class="widefat" name="reward_description[]" ></textarea></td>

        <td><input type="image" class="remove-row" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/images/remove-icon.png" alt="Submit"  width="35" height="35"></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>

    </table>

    <p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add Reward</a></p>

<?php   

}

function save_project_reward( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['project_reward_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['project_reward_nonce'], 'project_reward_nonce' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    }
    else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    $reward_data = array();
    $options = project_rewards_select_options();

    $rewards = $_POST['reward'];
    $reward_titles = $_POST['reward_title'];
    $reward_shippings = $_POST['reward_shipping'];
    $reward_dates = $_POST['reward_date'];    
    $reward_descriptions = $_POST['reward_description'];

    $count = count( $rewards );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {

        if ( $rewards[$i] != '' ) :
            $reward_data[$i]['reward'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $rewards[$i] ) );

        if ( in_array( $reward_shippings[$i], $options ) )
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_shipping'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $reward_shippings[$i] ) );
                else
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_shipping'] = '';
endif;

        if ( $reward_titles[$i] != '' ) :
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_title'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $reward_titles[$i] ) );
endif;

        if ( $reward_descriptions[$i] != '' ) :
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_description'] = stripslashes( $reward_descriptions[$i] );
endif;

        if ( $reward_descriptions[$i] != '' ) :
            $reward_data[$i]['reward_date'] = stripslashes( $reward_dates[$i] );
endif;            

    }

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_project_rewards', $reward_data );

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_project_reward' );
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get notified, I just now saw that you tried to reach me. I will update my answer asap.